# Unable to do any installation with apt or dpkg: --fix-broken not working

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

When I wanted to run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`, came up with an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock is already the newest version (0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I searced across the web and tried different solutions. In conclusion, when I run `sudo apt install -f`, the output is:

```
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01  libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1 [42,3 MB]
(Reading database ... 292882 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcublas-dev (10.2.2.89-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/nvblas.h', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 9.1.85-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried to `sudo apt remove nvidia-cuda-dev`. The output is:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even when I run `sudo apt purge nvidia*` or `cuda*`, the output is:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-dkms-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-driver-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-utils-440 (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-modprobe (>= 440.33.01)
                Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 440.33.01) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This really took all of my energy. Can someone help please?

Comment: Why did you want to install `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` as the output tells it is installed already?

Comment: Yea, I didn't know it's installed when I tried to. It happens for uninstalled packages too.

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048021/cuda-setup-and-installation/error-depends-libcublas-dev-gt-10-1-0-105-but-it-is-not-installed-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Thanks, I'm investigating it